# Selenium Test Fails (incorrectly) on Assertion and doesn't continue as expected

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a set of Selenium tests (C# and SpecFlow) which should fail at a certain point. The Failure is in asserting that some data on the page is correct (which it is not) however my problem is the test stops completely and shows a stack trace error instead of continuing.

[image: Stack Trace and Scenario]

This is not what I want. I want the test to show the failure steps, but it stops once it hits the first failure and doesn't find the others. I'm not sure what I am missing (it's 6am and I've been working for 14 hours straight).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for soft assertions https://automationrhapsody.com/soft-assertions-c-unit-testing-frameworks-mstest-nunit-xunit-net/ . Also add tag of specflow in your question.

Comment: `however my problem is the test stops completely and shows a stack trace error instead of continuing.` that's the whole purpose of the assertions :)

Comment: If an `Assert.AreEqual()` fails, then an `AssertionException` is thrown. If this exception is unhandled, then the exception will bubble up and lead to the termination of the tests. This is typically desirable behavior; however, if you want to assert against multiple values, then you must either handle the exception, typically done in a [`Try-Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) block, or with an alternate method of asserting against values, such as @RahulL's suggestion on "soft assertions".

Comment: OK fine then, other apps I've used don't stop when an assertion fails, they just show a fail counters. That's fine then. Thanks!